# li not displaying inline

Tags: php, html, css, block, inline

I am displaying a list of movies from a database- they are supposed to be displaying inline, but they are displaying vertically instead. I have tried using inline-block for li as well as inline, but nothing is working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
.movienav {
    height: 500px;
    width:75%; 
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px; 
    clear:left;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.movienav li {
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;

}

.movienav li div {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #161616;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:inline;

}

.movienav li div.back {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    left: -999em;
    padding-bottom: 15px;  
    background-color:#161616; /*max-height:450px; overflow:auto;*/
    margin-top: 0;
    display:inline;

}

<div class="movienav">
<ul>
<li><div class="front"><img src="<?php echo $imglink; ?>" width="340" height="450" class="dvdcover" /></div>
<div class="back">


<p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML and not the PHP.

Comment: Flag for duplication
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858399/php-li-not-displaying-inline-despite-displayinline
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857700/li-not-displaying-inline

Answer (score 3):

The `<div>`s and the `<p>` within the `<li>` are block elements. You should place `display:inline` on those `<div>`s and `<p>`.

Also, any HTML in the `$description` variable that are block-level elements are going to cause the same behavior.

**EDIT:** You have much bigger problems on your site that are causing the issue.

You are repeating your `<div id="movienav"></div>` code over and over again, each with a `<ul>` and one `<li>` item in it. Firstly, you cannot have more than on container with the same, unique ID on it. Second, those `<div>`s are block elements, thus why they are not displaying inline.

You need to set up your structure to look more like this:

```
<div id="movienav">
  <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not the way you have it, then your style should work fine.

Comment: I added display-inline to li div and li div.back and no luck

Comment: I changed #movienav p to display:inline as well and still no luck

Comment: Michael- I changed to a class, but I cannot implement the li structure you are suggesting as the movies are coming from a database.

Comment: Not sure how to code it- If I repeat the code, adding another li inside the ul, the same movie is repeated.

Comment: I will open a new discussion- thanks

Comment: *"Second, those `<div>`s are block elements, thus why they are not floating."* - What does that have to do with anything? You can float block-level elements. Any element can be floated, and all floated elements inherit `display: inline-block` automatically, which can't be overridden while it's still being floated.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @animuson, type on my part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display them in one line you can use `float` property.

```
li { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This will display them in one line but not as inline elements (they will still be block elements).

Comment: I already have float:left; on the li