# PHP: li not displaying inline despite display:inline

Tags: html, css

I am displaying a list of movies from a database- they are supposed to be displaying inline, but they are displaying vertically instead. Here is a [test page](http://tinyurl.com/bkdqvf7).

I have added display:inline to li and inner divs, but still no luck-

```
.movienav {
    height: 500px;
    width:75%; 
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px; 
    clear:left;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.movienav li {
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;

}

.movienav li div {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    width: 340px;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #161616;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:inline;

}

.movienav li div.back {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    left: -999em;
    padding-bottom: 15px;  
    background-color:#161616; /*max-height:450px; overflow:auto;*/
    margin-top: 0;
    display:inline;

}

<div class="movienav">
<ul>
<li><div class="front"><img src="<?php echo $imglink; ?>" width="340" height="450" class="dvdcover" /></div>
<div class="back">


<p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857700/li-not-displaying-inline?

Comment: Flag for duplication
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858399/php-li-not-displaying-inline-despite-displayinline
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857700/li-not-displaying-inline

Answer (score 2):

You have each LI wrapped it its own UL and DIV. I'm only guessing, but you may be able to fix it with

```
.movienav {float: none;}
```